# Google visualization API (gviz) query and fetching data from a spreadsheet

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, urlfetch

I am using the Google Visualization API to query a spreadsheet. If I paste the URL in the browser:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14dIMLkVwHRo-bkvdIhaDwC-rGBHLefftlC6CCCs5YrWSc/gviz/tq?sheet=customers&tq=select+*+Where+A='27938'
```

A is the customer ID column. I get this JSON looking text back:
`google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"7671558882","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"ID","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"FirstName",.....`

1) How can I do the same within a google script function (not from the client side javascript function)?

I tried using the URLFetchApp.fetc():

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14dIMLkVwHRo-bkvdIhaDwC-rGBHLefftlC6CCCs5YrWSc/gviz/tq?sheet=customers&tq=select+*+Where+A=27938'
var result = URLFetchApp.fetch(url);
var out = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
Logger.log(out);
```

The logger shows a long list of CSS style definitions and HTML tags. If I can get the JSON response and parse it, I was planning to do some business logic within the function return a value to the client.

Answer (score 2):

I found problems with google sheets/gvis query too - for unnown reason Google Sheets returns not pure JSON but add some s*** to it, so before use JSON.parse() we need to cut it of (or crop the usefull part of the response):

```
var httpresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlrequest, options).getContentText();

var from = httpresponse.indexOf("{");
var to   = httpresponse.lastIndexOf("}")+1;

var jsonText = httpresponse.slice(from, to);

var parsedText = JSON.parse(jsonText);
```

Comment: The s*** in question is called [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and it is a security device.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to call the function openByID in apss script ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openByUrl(String))) then call the method  getRange(), then you will receive a two dimension array with the information of the sheet.

with this then you can create the JSON to use the chart services ([docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/?csw=1))

There are probably some libraries that already. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/notable-script-libraries) website, you may find the one you need.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting "CSS style definitions and HTML tags" is the error in the request.

Here's the error text:

> This spreadsheet is not publicly viewable and requires an OAuth
>   credential.  For more information, see
>   https://support.google.com/docs/?p=gviz_tq_auth

Share the file to solve it:

[image]

Here's the sample code I used to get the query result as 2D array:

## Usage

```
function test_getSheetsQueryResult()
{
  var fileId = '1WO3PEycHGtfG-yd4V-B6EfKkVYMC73EqDBPqgAqcz3k';
  var sheetName = 'Data';
  var rangeA1 = 'A1:H11';
  var sqlText = "select A, C, D, F, 'google' where E > 0";

  var res = getSheetsQueryResult_(fileId, sheetName, rangeA1, sqlText);
  Logger.log(res);

}
```

## Code:

```
/*   
  Types:

    Get             Return
    number    =>    number
    string    =>    string
    date      =>    string
    datetime  =>    string
    boolean   =>    boolean

  Note: 

    The function returns strings for dates because of 2 resons:
      1. The string is automatically converted into a date when pasted into the sheet
      2. There are multiple issues with dates (like different time zones) that could modify returned values
*/
function getSheetsQueryResult_(fileId, sheetName, rangeA1, sqlText)
{

  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
  var sheetId = file.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId();

  var request = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + fileId + '/gviz/tq?gid=' + sheetId + '&range=' + rangeA1 + '&tq=' + encodeURIComponent(sqlText);
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request).getContentText();     
  // get json object
  var from = result.indexOf("{");
  var to   = result.lastIndexOf("}")+1;  
  var jsonText = result.slice(from, to);  
  var parsedText = JSON.parse(jsonText);      

  // get types
  var types = [];
  var addType_ = function(col) { types.push(col.type); }
  var cols = parsedText.table.cols;
  cols.forEach(addType_);    

  // loop rows
  var rows = parsedText.table.rows;  
  var result = [];  
  var rowQuery = [];
  var eltQuery = {};
  var row = [];
  var nRows = rows[0].c.length;
  var type = '';
  for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++)
  {
    rowQuery = rows[i].c;
    row = [];
    // loop values   
    for (var k = 0; k < nRows; k++)
    {
      eltQuery = rowQuery[k];
      type = types[k];
      if (type === 'number') { row.push(parseInt(eltQuery.v)); }
      if (type === 'boolean' || type === 'string') { row.push(eltQuery.v); }
      else { row.push(eltQuery.f); }      
    }    
    result.push(row);
  }

  return result;

}
```