# I'm currently trying to create a chrome extension (ContextMenu with right click search)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to include an option which will redirect the user to the google sheets page and select a particular cell as per the selection text in the UI. I already created the contextmenu extension and also associated the google sheets URL  in the JavaScript code and it's redirecting as intended.

All that I would like to know is, how can we let the system know that once it reaches the required document, what is the procedure to find a cell in the sheet using URL itself?

Like is there any command we can use after #gid=0, because #fragments would generally mean the end of the parameters and will ignore anything coinciding with it.

I've tried using '/search?q=query' after the doc URL, but no luck

let url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/fileID/edit#gid=0'

Comment: Googling for "link to specific cell in google sheets" reveals some answers like [Link to a cell in a Google Sheets via URL?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44473)

Comment: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[ID-HERE]/edit#gid=0&range=[RANGE-HERE]`

Comment: @Madhurjya, the range function will help us select that particular cell in the sheet. Like if you've a text which is at cell: D10, you paste that in range=D10 and cell will be selected.. But how about a user directly like to search for a text from a website and check if that's available in the Google sheets, is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think you got the requirement! I'm looking something sort of this to use in a contectMenu extension.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202686/google-visualization-api-gviz-query-and-fetching-data-from-a-spreadsheet) will help you.

Comment: Does returning the values as `JSON` meet your requirements? @VenkatAdithya

Comment: I'll try and check this now and will let you know accordingly. Thanks for the help! @Madhurjya